# one more in description

Tags: asp.net

last time it was pbl with the enc and storing it the db and now the pbl is in dec and retrieving the data from the db it is showing the error as

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space
>   character among the padding characters

**code is like this**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from admin where USERNAME=@USERNAME and PASSWORD=@PASSWORD ", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
            string strpassword = DecodeFrom64(txtPassword.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("emplist.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
            con1.Close();
        }
        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUserName.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
        }
        public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
        {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
            byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
            int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
            char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
            utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
            string result = new String(decoded_char);
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @user2189723 please give proper title name.

Comment: You don't / can't tag a person in the question, I said if its a new problem then ask a new question. Also you need to give better title to your question otherwise you might get downvotes.

Comment: Please write out entire words, instead of using shorthand.  The way you keep writing things like "pbl" and "enc" makes your question very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that I am not Habib, but

`txtPassword.Text` will have the text entered by the user. Users mostly don't enter Base64 encoded data. To assume that the password a user enters would be Base64 encoded is totally wrong.

Getting rid of this line should help

```
string strpassword = DecodeFrom64(txtPassword.Text);
```

You don't even seem to use it later.

Also, if you want to encrypt a password, use a one way hash like SHA with a salt. Base64 isn't going to encrypt it. Although it will not be clear text, it is very easy to decode.

**EDIT:**
To match an encoded password, you need to encode the password entered by the user and then select.

```
string strpassword = EncodeToBase64(txtPassword.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", strpassword);
```

Comment: i want to deccrept the data from the db and how it should be with the same ste of coding....,

Comment: how to do that nunespascal
sir...,

Comment: You can only decode what you have already encoded. So it depends on how you encoded it. To compare a password with what you have encoded in the db, you have to encode the user entered password, not decode it.

Comment: ya plz see my two taged quetion one is encription and decreption while adding the record and the other one is one more in description you will get an idea...,

Comment: @Habib,i am waiting for your replay sir.....,

Comment: @user2189723, nunespascal, has pointed you to the right place, also you don't tag a person to a question, consider this question as a new one and present your problem so that the people can help you

Comment: Check my edit. I still suggest encrypting the passwords and not just encoding them.